# Querying properties and handling events for built-in control in Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible to handle events for built-in controls in Outlook and/or query their values?

I'm coding for Outlook 2010 and 2013. I would like to know when a user changes a value of a control on the ribbon and on the File/Info pane when composing an email and get the values of these controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do anything with the built-in Ribbon controls is to repurpose them.
See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944181(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944181%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually tried that, but my events were not getting fired so I guess I assumed you couldn't do it. I'm trying to capture events and/or values for these. 

GroupRightsManagement  group
PermissionRestrictMenu  splitButton
PermissionRestrict  toggleButton
PermissionPoliciesOutlook toggleButton

Comment: Does Outlook show any errors if enable user interface errors in Outlook?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that option was there. 
"PermissionPoliciesOutlook" is not a repurposable command. Only "button", "toggleButton", and "checkBox" can have onAction callbacks in <commands>.
However, Microsoft documentation says it's a togglebutton.
Any idea how (if possible) I can query the properties of these controls?  This control has a drop down menu and I want to know what the user selected.

Comment: I can only think of UI Automation or Accessibility API to access these controls. What do you see in the Object Inspector (inspect.exe) from the Windows SDK?